# Customize default DatePickerFlyout element

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, controltemplate

Is there any way to customize [DatePickerFlyout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepickerflyout.aspx) in Windows Phone 8.1 application (WinRT, not Silverlight) like **Foreground**/**Background**/**BorderColor** brushes at least since the whole "control" template seems not available via expected common public property.

Comment: Did you try pulling out the style templates? Right-click "Edit Template->Edit a copy or may be in "Edit Additional Templates"? It has to be in there somewhere if you keep digging.

Comment: @ChrisW., where should I try to "right-click"? This class is not one of the [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx) descendants, so you can't put it inside the element tree in XAML as far as I understand.

Comment: Start at your date picker and work your way in from there, somewhere there has to be a template for it, I'd be very surprised if they generated it in procedural code as opposed to xaml.

Comment: DatePicker default styles and templates are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn481539.aspx).

Comment: @NateDiamond, having same prob. where is the Style and Template for DatePickerFlyout ?